# R Script in AzureML

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to develop a survey App and using R Script with Azure ML for same.

I have developed below code for the same and it works perfectly fine on Local Machine:

```
dataset1 <-maml.mapInputPort(2)
dataset3 <-maml.mapInputPort(1)
Z <- as.numeric((dataset3),stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
Y <- mdBinaryDesign(Z,4,dataset1)
Y.aggregate=mdBinaryToAggregateDesign(Y)
survey.design=mdDesignNames(Y.aggregate, dataset1)
data.set <- as.data.frame(survey.design)
maml.mapOutputPort("data.set")
```

Now we plan to deploy this Application on server , for which we are using Azure MIL .

Now my Dataset1 and Dataset3 are coming using Input port in R Model , by using the above code , I get error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". My Dataset3 contains a simple number eg: "5" .

Since my model will only run having three dynamic inputs (e.g. a, b, c), is there a way I can call a web service which will give me three output parameters via JSON and I can assign same to my model?

The part where I want to dynamically apply parameters are:

```
Y <- mdBinaryDesign(parameter_1,parameter_2,parameters3)
```

Since I am new to R , Please suggest we what library to use as well how to assigns value to parameter_1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your values for Dataset3 as a data.frame to be accepted as an input.

You can then extract the values from the data.frame inside Execute R Script and use them for your function.